# Gdb terminates when writing to an address in Linux

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio, pointers, gcc

The code block below is supposed to find each ';' character in a given string and replace it with '\0' character. The code works under Windows (Visual Studio 2015) but terminates suddenly in Eclipse cdt in this line (*ptr = replace;).

```
uint8_t *connstr = "/dev/ttyACM0;UID=;PWD=;ROLE=;";

void _creplace_char(uint8_t **in_str, uint8_t find, uint8_t replace)
{
    uint16_t str_len = (uint16_t)strlens(*in_str);
    uint8_t *ptr = (*in_str) + str_len - 1;

    while(str_len--)
    {
        if (*ptr == find)
            *ptr = replace;
        ptr--;
    }
}
```

I call the function as below:

```
_creplace_char(&connstr, ';', '\0');
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: You're attempting to modify a read-only string. Change `uint8_t *connstr = "/dev/ttyACM0;UID=;PWD=;ROLE=;";` to `uint8_t connstr[] = "/dev/ttyACM0;UID=;PWD=;ROLE=;";`

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Comment: You could skip the strlen and walk the string only once with something like `uint8_t *p = *in_str; while(1) { if (*p == '\0' ) break; if (*p == find) *p = replace; p++; }`